# Bootloader cannot be installed

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, bootloader

Recently I received a Sony Vaio that I have decided to wipe and put Ubuntu on. When running the installation, I get an error message telling me that the boot loader cannot be installed. I get three options: pick a new location, continue without boot-loader, cancel installation. None of these will even allow me to click them, and none of the different things I have done to the installation have seemed to work. I've tried not installing updates, running without internet, etc. and none of them seem to be the issue. Could it be the fact that it is installing over an existing Windows 7 with its bootloader without deleting Window's bootloader.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Newer UEFI system or older BIOS? And if UEFI hardware are you installing in UEFI or BIOS mode. What model Sony Vaio.

Comment: @oldfred It is older BIOS, don't think it would be classified as a newer UEFI system but I may be wrong. There is two model numbers on the back, its either model # PCG-31112L or model # VPC-Z1190X

Comment: If BIOS, grub should just install to MBR. But if UEFI you have to have the ESP or efi system partition. Or if BIOS and Windows was UEFI, then drive was gpt partitioned. And BIOS mode install of Ubuntu on gpt drives requires a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag to install. Post this above to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred Sorry for all the questions, I am new to Ubuntu and Linux. Where do I need to put sudo parted -l? If possible, would it be better to continue the install and install bootloader in different location after continuing the rest of the install? The only issue with doing that is that I am unable to click anything in the bootloader error menu except the options, and am unable to continue through setup.

Comment: You can finish install, but it still will not be bootable. Just wanted to see partitions to know for sure if gpt or MBR. Or possibly why error on install. You did specify to install grub2's boot loader to the drive like sda, if using Something Else to install, not to a partition?